# Converting a xlsx excel file to CSV comma delimited and quoted identifiers in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a requirement to covert an xlsx file to csv, ensuring that the values are quoted in double quotes.

So far I have researched on SO, and this is what I have tested so far, what the code doesn't do is quote the values in a double quote.

```
Function ExcelToCsv ($File) {
    $myDir = "C:\temp\"
    $excelFile = "$myDir\" + $File + ".xlsx"
    $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $wb = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($excelFile)
    
    foreach ($ws in $wb.Worksheets) {
        $ws.SaveAs("$myDir\" + $File + ".csv", 62)
    }
    $Excel.Quit()
}

$FileName = "test_file"
ExcelToCsv -File $FileName
```

The final output should look like the below.

```
Name,CompanyName
"Joe Bloggs","Contoso Company"
```

Comment: Excel quotes when needed. The easiest way would be tyo use `Import-Csv` after Excel has writen the file and then re-save the file with `Export-Csv`

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution but I'd start by using the [`ImportExcel`](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) module to import the Excel document, and then:

```
$Excel = Import-Excel .\exceltocsv.xlsx
$Excel | Export-Csv converted.csv
$Content = Get-Content .\converted.csv
$Content[0] = $Content[0] -replace '"',''
$Content | Out-File .\converted.csv
```

Output:

```
Column1,Column2
"Some Value","Something else"
```

Note that `Out-File` leaves a trailing line.